# Svelte field with a fixed length

Tags: javascript, svelte-3

I am developing a Svelte app; and I want to display multiple lines with 5 fields, in this case.
One of the fields contains a description, and to line out this field, I want to give it a fixed length.

I tried this JavaScript function:

```js
const fixLen = str => {
    let l = str.length;
    let s2 = "                    "; // 20 spaces
    let s3 = str + s2.substring(1, 21 - l);
    console.log(s3, s3.length);
    return s3;
  };
```

In Svelte:

```
{#each records as record}
  <div>
    {record.date} {fixLen(record.desc)} {record.ref1} {record.accNo}
    {record.amount.toFixed(2)}
  </div>
{/each}
```

In the hope that all description fields would now have the same length. But this does not work! The output is these 2 lines:

```
140318 ddddd ddddddd CK9730 7630 200.00
140318 dddd CK9731 7650 300.00
```

The d's are the descriptions.

What am I doing wrong? Doe sanyone have a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on JavaScript to do this you could do this with CSS by wrapping that one field in a span and setting a width to it of 20 characters.

```html
<style>
    span { display: inline-block; width: 20ch; }
</style>

{#each records as record}
  <div>
    {record.date} <span>{record.desc}</span> {record.ref1} {record.accNo} {record.amount.toFixed(2)}
  </div>
{/each}
```

From a pure semantic markup point of view, it looks like you're making some kind of table, in which case I suppose it would be better to use a table.

Comment: Indeed; using a table is better.